# как сделать добавление блоков влево а не вниз

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3

По клику на кнопку js формирует минимальный блок, которые я хочу размещать в мини полосу прокрутки

```js
$('#add-photo').on('click', function() {
  let add = '<div class="image-block"><div class="image"></div><input type="text" name="photo_name" class="notot-name-position"></div>'
  $('.photo-list').append(add)
})
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#add-photo {
  margin: 150px 0 15px 0;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.photo-list {
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #3097D1;
  padding: 5px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow-y: scroll; !* прокрутка по вертикали *!*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.image-block {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <button id="add-photo">Add photo</button>
  <div class="photo-list">

  </div>
</div>
```

[Для наглядности](https://codepen.io/coding_bee/pen/oMKxLN)

Какого свойства мне не хватает? Спасибо

Comment: Для добавления блока в начало используется метод `.prepend()`. `append()`  добавляет в конец. Для того чтобы блоки не переносились можно использовать `css flex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display: flex;` - надо задать родителю

```js
$('#add-photo').on('click', function() {
  let add = '<div class="image-block"><div class="image"></div><input type="text" name="photo_name" class="notot-name-position"></div>'
  $('.photo-list').append(add)
})
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#add-photo {
  margin: 150px 0 15px 0;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.photo-list {
  display: flex;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #3097D1;
  padding: 5px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow-y: scroll; !* прокрутка по вертикали *!*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.image-block {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <button id="add-photo">Add photo</button>
  <div class="photo-list">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно нужно добавить к стилям в класс `.image-block`

```
display: inline-block;
```